# Don't understand why I'm getting "Error inflating class Fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning how to work with fragments in Android and I worked on the Google fragment example to build a sample fragment. However it keeps giving me this error

```
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tesingfragments/com.example.tesingfragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class Fragment
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class Fragment
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at com.example.tesingfragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     ... 11 more
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tesingfragments-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.tesingfragments-1, /system/lib]]
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-08 02:31:31.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2073):     ... 21 more
```

This is what I did.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.tesingfragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

MainActivity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.tesingfragments.Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.tesingfragments.Fragment2"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        /> 
   <!--  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/texter1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Fragment 1"
     />--> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment 1

```
package com.example.tesingfragments;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenter, container, false);
    }

}
```

Fragment 1 layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Fragment 1"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment 2

```
package com.example.tesingfragments;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

Fragment 2 layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Fragment 2"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my explorer view so you can see that I named the classes properly.

[image: This]

Comment: your `<Fragment` should it not be `<fragment`?

Comment: also is what is your min sdk in manifest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace  `<Fragment` by <`fragment` in your xml.

Check the docs for more info

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

Edit:

Also extend `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I fixed it to lower case f and set the min sdk to 11, but I still get the same error. Even after cleaning the project.

Comment: you should extend activity. instead of fragment activity

Comment: also it looks like there is a problem with your build path

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: you should extend activity not fragment activity. give it a try

Comment: Yeah, that worked. But I don't know why it worked. The google example extended FragmentActivity.

Comment: it depends on your min sdk if its 100 then extend `Fragmentactivity` and use `SupportFragment` with android backward compatibility library. Note fragments were introduced in honeycomb api 11.

Comment: My min sdk is 11. What does that imply?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35055/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-michael-nana)